# Rails jQuery sortable unable to save

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, acts-as-list

I'm trying to make my table sortable (drag and drop) using jQuery, the problem I'm having is saving the new sorted table and then publishing it to other users or when the browser is refreshed.

I'm using:

gem 'acts_as_list'
Rails 3.2.17
ruby 1.9.3p484

Is there a better way of doing this?

my sort and show method on my controller

def sort 
    @episodes = current_user.episodes_for(@show).each do |episode|
      episode.position = params['episode'].index(episode.id.to_s) + 1
      episode.save
    end
      render :nothing =>true
  end

```
  def show
    @episodes = current_user.episodes_for(@show)
    @episodes.order('episode.position ASC')
    @episode = @episodes.where(id: params[:id]).first
  end
```

My Javascript

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#sortthis").sortable({
      axis: 'y',
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
      cursor: 'move',
      dropOnempty: false,
      scroll: true,
      opacity: 0.4,

      update: function(event, ui){
        var itm_arr = $("#sortthis").sortable('toArray');
        var pobj = {episodes: itm_arr};
        $.post("/episodes/sort", pobj);
      }

    });
});
 </script>
```

The table I wanna sort in views:

```
<tbody id='eps'>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Season</th>
  <th>Download?</th>
  <th>Shared?</th>
  <th>Length</th>
  <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
</tr>
<% for episode in @episodes %>
  <tr>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>", width="20%"><%=h episode.title %></td>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>"><%=h episode.number %></td>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>"><%=h episode.season %></td>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>"><%=h episode.is_downloadable %></td>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>"><%=h episode.shared_with_dev %></td>
    <td id="eps_<%= episode.id %>"><%=h episode.length %></td>
    <td>
      <% if episode.video %>
        <%= link_to 'Replace Video', new_show_episode_video_path(episode.show, episode) %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Upload Video', new_show_episode_video_path(episode.show, episode) %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
        <td>
        <%= link_to "View", [episode.show, episode] %> &nbsp;
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_show_episode_path(episode.show, episode) if permitted_to? :update, episode %> &nbsp;
    <%= link_to "Delete", show_episode_path(episode.show, episode), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete if permitted_to? :delete, episode %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, made the following changes:

Views:

```
<tr id="<%= episode.id %>">
```

and new controller

```
def sort
  Episode.all.each do |e|
    if position = params[:episodes].index(e.id.to_s)
      e.update_attribute(:position, position + 1) unless e.position == position + 1
    end
  end
  render :nothing => true, :status => 200
end
```

finally added this to my model:

```
  acts_as_list
  default_scope order('position')
```

let me know if anyone's having similar issues.